# SharePoint REST API - create Modern Site Collections

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to use the SharePoint REST API to create a modern SharePoint Site Collection in SharePoint Online.

I'm using the `_api/SPSiteManager/create` API to create the new site.

I have used the `App Only model` to create an app with the approprate permissons and I can obtain a token.
But when I make the POST call with the token I get the following error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
        <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 
    0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))</m:message>
    </m:error>
```

The body that I'm using with the post is the below:

```
{"request": { 
  "Title": "Communication Site 1",
  "Url":"https://[mytenancy].sharepoint.com/sites/commsite1",
  "Lcid": 1033,
  "ShareByEmailEnabled":false,
  "Description":"Description",
  "WebTemplate":"SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
  "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
  "Owner":"[accountid]@[mytenancy].onmicrosoft.com",
  "WebTemplateExtensionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}}
```

The App has been granted the following permissions

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"> 
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" 
  Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

It's pretty much a standard post using as much of the documentation as I can find.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Since the app only model, basically, adds an app context on a site collection, could you please share with us on which site collection did you create the App Registration?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have register sharepoint app in admin center like following

```
https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
```

I can use following rest api to create a site by the app

```
url: /_api/SPSiteManager/create
accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
method: POST

Body: 

     {
        "request": {
        "Title": "xiexinCommunication Site 2",
        "Url":"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xiexincommsite2",
        "Lcid": 1033,
        "ShareByEmailEnabled":false,
        "Classification":"Low Business Impact",
        "Description":"Description",
        "WebTemplate":"SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0",
        "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
        "Owner":"xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
        "WebTemplateExtensionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
    }
```